Accumulation point notion in the derivative definition
According to $[1]$ we have:
Definition $\mathbf{13.1.3}$ (Derivative at $x_0$). Let $f：X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function and
$x_{0}\;\in\;X^{\prime}\;{\cap}\;X.$ The derivative of the function
$f$ at the point $x_0$ is defined as the limit of the difference quotient
$$
\lim_{x \to x_{0}}\Delta_{x_{0}}f(x)=\lim_{x \to x_{0}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}},\tag{1}
$$
if it exists. If this limit exists, we call the function $f$
differentiable at $x_0$. We denote the value of this limit as
$f^{\prime}(x_{0})$
Given a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, the $X'\subset \mathbb{R}$ is the set of limit points of $X$ and according to $[1]$ limit points (or cluster point or accumulation points) are defined as:
Definition $\mathbf{6.2.2}$ (Limit Point of a Set). Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. A point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of the set $X$ if, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, the set $X \cap (B_\varepsilon(x) -\{x\}) $ is non-empty, where $B_\varepsilon(x)=(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$.
So, in order to evaluate a limit as in $(1)$ we need evaluate the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} q(x)$, where $q: X-\{x_0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $q(x)=\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0}$. So, $x_0$ need to be a limit point of the set $X-\{x_0\}$ that is $x_0 \in (X-\{x_0\})'$, due to the limit definition:
Definition $\mathbf{9.2.6}$ (Limit of a Function at $x_0$). Let $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0 \in X'$. The function $f$ has the limit $L \in \mathbb{R}$ as $x \rightarrow x_0$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta(\varepsilon) > 0$ such that for all $x \in X$ with $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta(\varepsilon)$ we have $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$. We write this as
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)=L.
$$
However, in Definition $\mathbf{13.1.3}$ is only considered $x_0 \in X'\cap X$.
Question. $x_0 \in X'\cap X \iff x_0 \in \big(X-\{x_0\}\big)'$?
In $[1]$, immediately above Definition $13.1.3$, the author claims that $x_0 \in X'\cap X \implies x_0 \in \big(X-\{x_0\}\big)'$? But, why?
I believe the statement in the Question follows by means manipulations properties of sets, since, from the general property $A \cap (B-C)=(A-B)\cap (A-C)$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
 \big(X-\{x_0\}\big) \cap \big( B_\varepsilon(x_0)-\{x_0\} \big) &=& \big( (X-\{x_0\})\cap B_\varepsilon(x_0) \big)- \overbrace{\big(  (X-\{x_0\})  \cap \{x_0\} \big)}^{=\emptyset}\\
&=& \big( (X-\{x_0\})\cap B_\varepsilon(x_0) \big) \\
& = &  X\cap \big( B_\varepsilon(x_0)-\{x_0\} \big), 
\end{eqnarray}
where
\begin{eqnarray}
 x_0 \in \big(X-\{x_0\}\big)' & \implies & \big(X-\{x_0\}\big) \cap \big( B_\varepsilon(x_0)-\{x_0\} \big) \\
\text{and} \qquad x_0 \in X'& \implies &  X\cap \big( B_\varepsilon(x_0)-\{x_0\} \big).
\end{eqnarray}
That is correct?
$[1]$ Johar, S., The Big Book of Real Analysis - From Numbers to Measures, Springer Cham, $2024$.

It is easy to show. The key is that removing an element that is not already contained in a set does not change the set; i.e.,
$$\left( X - \{ x_0 \} \right) - \{ x_0 \} = X - \{ x_0 \}$$
for any $x_0$. I will leave it for you to check this simple fact.
($\implies$) Let $x_0 \in X' \cap X$; i.e., $x_0$ is an element of $X$ such that every neighborhood of $x_0$ intersects $X - \{ x_0 \}$. By hypothesis, every neighborhood of $x_0$ intersects $X - \{ x_0 \}$, and hence also intersects $\left( X - \{ x_0 \} \right) - \{ x_0 \}$. Therefore, $x \in \left( X - \{ x_0 \} \right)'$, as desired.
The converse, however, is not true, because even though $x_0 \in \left( X - \{ x_0 \} \right)'$ implies that $x_0 \in X'$, this does not necessarily place $x_0$ in $X$. As an example, take $X = [0, 1)$ and $x_0 = 1$. Obviously,
$$x_0 \in [0, 1] = [0, 1)' = X' = \left( X - \{ x_0 \} \right)'$$
but
$$x_0 \notin [0, 1) = X = X' \cap X$$

Great answer. Thank you!
